# Api for Save/Select List of Reference type into redis

Tags: caching, c#-4.0, redis, stackexchange.redis, .net-4.5.2

I am using stackexchange.redis api to access simple List of string into Redis. Now I needed to Add/Update/Delete/Get List into redis
Then Access the objects like lst.Find(h=>h.Id == "1") e.t.c
Basically a functionality to Manipulate ReferenceType object.
I can't find it build in there. Anybody know how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a broad subject. There are two ways of storing complex objects in Redis: serialization, and hashes. Serialization is opaque blobs - only(usually) interpreted by the calling application. I discussed this in this [github issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/325) that I suspect is also you. Hashes are name/value pairs inside a single key (kinda like dynamic database columns, ... -ish) - this allows fetch of a subset of properties, etc.

Note that you can't have hashes inside lists.

Next we have the issue of lookup by an id. If you use a Redis list, you can fetch by position only: not by some property. I suspect you're also thinking of Redis with RDBMS goggles, but Redis simply doesnt work like that.

Personally, I would have a key per item, named by the primary key. For example keys like `/user/12345`. Then fetching (or updating) user 12345 is a case of reading (or writing) to the key **by name**. Redis does not natively support additional indexing, but you can implement indexes manually using **additional** storage. For example, a hash in `/users/ssid` that maps `whatever572618` to the user that has that id.

Josiah Carlson's "Redis in Action" book may be of use to you in understanding how to work with Redis.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Now i am thinking about your suggestion of keys like MyListName/MyID .e.g.(SmsInList/1)  For That I think simple StackExchangeRedis implemenation might be enough. Only problem I was thinking for what should I do for the case where i were thinking about emtying the list. For That I think i have to now fetch All the keys who are starting with suffix of "MyListName/" and emptying it.
Thanks a lot again

Comment: @Kamran note: you should avoid any temptation to use "keys" or "scan" for that. You could store a Redis set of all ids and enumerate that, but frankly I'd be tempted to challenge the need to do that in the first place. Or I might consider putting them all in a specific database number and use "flushdb" which purges an entire database number at once.

Comment: I've worked on a library [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/blob/master/COLLECTIONS.md) based on the great StackExchange.Redis that abstract the serialization exposing an [API](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/blob/master/COLLECTIONS.md) for redis lists and hashes as .NET `IList<>` and `IDictionary<,>` objects. It can probably help.

Comment: Thanks thePirat000 . I was trying with an extension https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions (but doesn't find all what i wanted yet) But will see what this other cachingframework.redis do. Marc I doesn't know much about the databsenumber. I think i am just using single database. Will see about the different database option as well.
Thanks